# React props not updating on dispatch action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been searching for an answer for a few days now and it's getting really frustrating. I have started learning React just recently, and ran into this trouble: 
  I have a project reducer which is this (projectReducers.js):

```
const projectReducer = (state = {
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        item: {},
        items: []
    }, action) => 
{
switch(action.type){

    case 'GET_PROJECT_START':{
        state = { ...state, fetching: true};
    }
        break;
    case 'GET_PROJECT_RECEIVED':{
        state = {...state,  fetching: false, fetched: true, item: action.payload };
    }
        break;
    case 'GET_PROJECT_ERROR':{
        state = { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    }


    case 'GET_PROJECTS_START':{
        state = { ...state, fetching: true};
    }
        break;
    case 'GET_PROJECTS_RECEIVED':{
        state = {...state,  fetching: false, fetched: true, items: action.payload };
    }
        break;
    case 'GET_PROJECTS_ERROR':{
        state = { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    }
}
return state
};

export default projectReducer;
```

P.S. I know that GET_PROJECT_START and GET_PROJECTS_START do the same, I separated them just for my own clarity for now.

actions(projectActions.js):

```
export function createProject(number){
    return {
        type: 'CREATE_PROJECT',
        payload: number
        }
};

export function getProjectStart(){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECT_START'
    }
};

export function getProjectReceived(project){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECT_RECEIVED',
        payload: project
    }
};

export function getProjectError(err){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECT_ERROR',
        payload: err
    }
};

export function getProjectsStart(){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECTS_START'
    }
};

export function getProjectsReceived(projects){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECTS_RECEIVED',
        payload: projects
    }
};

export function getProjectsError(err){
    return {
        type: 'GET_PROJECTS_ERROR',
        payload: err
    }
};
```

I combine my reducers with combineReducers and create store (store.js):

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import mathReducer from './reducers/mathReducer'; //not relevant
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer'; //not relevant
import projectReducer from './reducers/projectReducer';

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({mathReducer, userReducer, projectReducer}),
    {},
    applyMiddleware(logger()) <- log changes
);
```

Wrap root component in Provider from react-redux to bind the store (Index.js)

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    window.document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And bind the store to root app props with connect (App.js)

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/blank" project={this.props.project} projectActions={this.props.projectActions} component={Projects}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        math: state.mathReducer,
        user: state.userReducer,
        project: state.projectReducer
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        projectActions :{
            getProjectStart: () => {dispatch(getProjectStart())},
            getProjectReceived: (project) => {dispatch(getProjectReceived(project))},
            getProjectError: (err) => {dispatch(getProjectError(err))},
            getProjectsStart: () => {dispatch(getProjectsStart())},
            getProjectsReceived: (project) => {dispatch(getProjectsReceived(project))},
            getProjectsError: (err) => {dispatch(getProjectsError(err))}
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

And then use the passed props in the (Projects.js) with fetching from the server:

```
export default class Projects extends React.Component {

    fetchProjects() {
        let projectActions = this.props.route.projectActions;
        projectActions.getProjectsStart();
        console.log(this.props.route.project);

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/projects/').then((response)=> {
            setTimeout(() => {
                projectActions.getProjectsReceived(response.json());
                console.log(this.props.route.project);
            }, 5000);

        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchProjects();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <h1>Projects</h1>
                    {this.props.route.project.fetching ? <span> receiving data</span> : <span> Not receiving data </span>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here the funny things happen the this.props.route.project never gets updated the span->not receiving data never changes even though I add a huge 5s delay. Yet the redux-logger which shows the (prev state | action | next state) shows all the correct changes. Where my binding goes wrong?

Comment: What worked in my case, added dispatchers onEnter inside the React Router. For that you will need redux-thunk, https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk.

Comment: Now I am completely messed up :D why is it that if I use your method, by adding onEnter={this.fetchProjects} it fetches them correctly, why can't I pass the dispachers as properties? :D Because if I use the onEnter I have to add them to the nextState and as I understand they should be passed as properties since the state is already managed by redux store :)

Comment: And yet still if I perform the fetching in the parent component, the child component still does not get updated :/

Comment: Okay now I moved the connect to the child component and everything seems to work, but this requires, that every component that needs access to either the store objects or dispachers should be connect with react-redux? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a little trickier to manage, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount is run before rendering, if you want an action to influence your rendering you should use componentDidMount.